# Intellij, Spring Boot e AngularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Estou executando um  projeto  `Spring Boot e AngularJs no Intellij` e estou tentando acessar a pasta `webapp` pelo navegar (l`ocalhost:8080/nomedapasta/index.html`), só que esta dando erro

> (There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404))

e não consegui resolver. Mas pelo eclipse eu consigo acessar o mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Na configuração do seu servidor, "Edit Configurations" em "Deployment" configura o Context Path, exemplo "minhaapp" e use da seguinte forma:

localhost:8080/minhaapp/index.html

Comment: Obrigado consegui revolver..